# Content being hidden by title and tabs in Ionic

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I have an index page which contains 3 tabs. The problem occurs within all tabs, but I will show here with the Home page. The problem that is occurring is that the some of the top content of the Home page is being overlapped by the title bar and the tabs bar so it is being hidden.

Inside of the Home html page I tried to wrap the code under with **ion-content** (see code below), but this hides the top content, squishes the height and it is no longer full screen, plus for the slides I have to swipe over the content because if I touch some of the padding or margin space it will not swipe anymore (slide 3 is a good example since it does not have a lot of content, you must press and swipe over the text for it to swipe). If I remove the ion-content tags, this adjusts the height properly, makes the swipe work so I don't have to swipe over content for it to work, but the problem of the top content being overlapped by the tabs and title bar still exists. How can I fit the home.html perfectly under the tabs and to utilize all the space?

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- ngCordova install script needed -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mobileApp">


  <script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab icon="ion-home-outline"  ui-sref="tabs.Home">
        <ion-nav-view name="Home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab icon="ion-info-outline" ui-sref="tabs.Info">
        <ion-nav-view name="Info-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab icon="ion-system-outline" ui-sref="tabs.System">
        <ion-nav-view name="System-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-calm">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view  hide-back-button="true">
      <ion-nav-title>
        <h1>TitleHere</h1>
      </ion-nav-title>
    </ion-view>
  </ion-nav-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-content>
        <div class="item item-checkbox">
            Checkbox Label
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox">
            </label>
        </div>

        <ion-slide-box>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Thank you for choosing the Awesome App!</h3>
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="http://code.ionicframework.com/assets/img/app_icon.png">
                </div>
                <p>
                    We've worked super hard to make you happy.
                </p>
                <p>
                    But if you are angry, too bad.
                </p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Using Awesome</h3>

                <div id="list">
                    <h5>Just three steps:</h5>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Be awesome</li>
                        <li>Stay awesome</li>
                        <li>There is no step 3</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Any questions?</h3>
                <p>
                    Too bad!
                </p>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>

 <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" >
   <div class="title">Footer</div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

With ion-content. The top checkbox is hidden, the footer is not on the bottom and swiping only works if I hold and swipe over content not over white space.
[image: With ion-content. The top checkbox is hidden, the footer is not on the bottom and swiping only works if I hold and swipe over content not over white space.]

If I remove ion-content. The footer goes to the bottom, I can swipe anywhere in the white and it will swipe, but the checkbox is still hidden by the title bar and the tabs.
[image: If I remove ion-content. The footer goes to the bottom, I can swipe anywhere in the white and it will swipe, but the checkbox is still hidden by the title bar and the tabs.]

Comment: Adding a few screenshots would help make the problem clearer.

Comment: @BenSmith Please see the updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I met this problem before when I tried Ionic in the first time. Having wasting a lot of time to solve this.
Some of your top content will be overlapped because the ion-tabs priority is higher than the content in the back.

I put the footer outside the `<ion-content>` tag. I placed some  class such as `has-tabs-top` and `has-footer`.

Try this and let me know if it can helps you.
http://codepen.io/nampdn/pen/qOKNNv

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
        <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content class="has-tabs-top has-footer" scroll="false">
        <div class="item item-checkbox">
          Checkbox Label
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox">
          </label>
        </div>
        <ion-slide-box>
          <ion-slide>
            <h3>Thank you for choosing the Awesome App!</h3>
            <div id="logo">
              <img src="http://code.ionicframework.com/assets/img/app_icon.png">
            </div>
            <p>
              We've worked super hard to make you happy.
            </p>
            <p>
              But if you are angry, too bad.
            </p>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h3>Using Awesome</h3>

            <div id="list">
              <h5>Just three steps:</h5>
              <ol>
                <li>Be awesome</li>
                <li>Stay awesome</li>
                <li>There is no step 3</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h3>Any questions?</h3>
            <p>
              Too bad!
            </p>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>


      </ion-content>
      <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
        <div class="title">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Facts">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
        <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
        <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
        <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
        <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
        <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
        <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
        <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
        <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
        <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="About">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
        <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
        <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Contact">
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item">
            @IonicFramework
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            @DriftyTeam
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works now, I spent days on this! Additional question. Just a side question, if I wanted to remove the top title bar, could I do this? I tried to remove the ion-nav-bar, but a then white space remains and the tabs don't move to the top, so there is just some whitespace on the top? PS I will give you bounty, but I must wait another 7 hours for it to let me do it.

Comment: Yes! You can remove it, that's my problem in the past, too.
I think it is too simple to "know". Here is the trick: In the `<ion-view>` tag, insert the `hide-nav-bar` ionic attribute and set it to `true` like this `<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">`

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm new member and I don't know how bounty works. Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: It is kind of an "extra" reward for helping me! http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty