# Ion-scroll inside ion-tab covering whole body

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a image inside a ion-tab and because the picture is bigger is size I used ion-scroll to easily view the image by scrolling.

The problem im facing is that the tab-content starts from where the tab view ends like this:-

[image]

But look at the ion-scroll or div with class scroll (which was added dynamically by ionic) covering the whole body.

[image]

Which should be inside ion-content and starts where the tab ends, and because of that the top of the image is hidden behind the tab.

This is the top of the image hidden behind tab, I have scrolled it down to show.

[image]

Can somebody help me fix it.

EDIT:
After spending some time on it I figured out that another div is added dynamically above  which set the translate 3d, look at the picture below:-

[image]

But actually my code looks like this:-

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-top">
        <!-- Main Billboard -->
        <ion-tab title="Main Billboard" href="#/home/main">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-main">
                <ion-content lazy-scroll>
                        <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: {{w}}px; height: {{h}}px">
                          <div data-images-loaded data-use-progress-events="yes">
                            <div style="width: 5000px; height: 4000px;float:left;">
                                    <img ng-src="{{src}}" usemap="#admap">
                                  <div style="display:none" style="width: 5000px; height: 4000px;float:left; background: url('{{src}}') no-repeat" style="display:none"> </div>
                            </div>

                            </div>

                            <map name="admap">
                                 <area shape="rect" coords="{{ad.x1}},{{ad.y1}},{{ad.x2}},{{ad.y2}}" ng-repeat="ad in mapdata" title="{{ad.title}}" ng-click="showModal({{ad.ad_id}})" target="_blank">';
                            </map>
                         </ion-scroll>
                </ion-content>


            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
```

When I try to change translate3d to transform: translate3d(0px, -91px, 0px) scale(1); it fix the problem but this div is added dynamically I can change it from code.

Comment: Create code snippet for this.

Comment: code is too complex to create a snippet, but i have exactly same problem as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361585/content-being-hidden-by-title-and-tabs-in-ionic but the solution doesnt work for me

Comment: Without code snippet it is very tough to solve your issue ..According to my view you are facing overlap problem . Try follwing code  in ionic content <ion-content class="has-header has-subheader">

Comment: after adding class has-header has-subheader the content is moved down but after after trying to fix it for few hours i figured out that ionic is adding another div above <ion-scroll> which set style transform: translate3d(0px, -179px, 0px) scale(1);

the value -179px is the cause the content is moved behind the tabs, when i try to change the value to -90 it fixed the problem but since it is dynamically added i cant change it from code

Comment: im updating the question to show it

Comment: please check the edit part

Comment: i tried to create a demo of the problem here http://play.ionic.io/app/6e106d97f60c